# MySQL SQL_NO_CACHE not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, innodb

I have a table (InnoDB) that gets inserted, updated and read frequently (usually in a burst of few milliseconds apart). I noticed that sometimes the SELECT statement that follows an INSERT/UPDATE would get stale data. I assume this was due to cache, but after putting `SQL_NO_CACHE` in front of it doesn't really do anything.

How do you make sure that the SELECT always wait until the previous INSERT/UPDATE finishes and not get the data from cache? Note that these statements are executed from separate requests (not within the same code execution).

Maybe I am misunderstanding what SQL_NO_CACHE actually does...

**UPDATE**:

@Uday, the INSERT, SELECT and UPDATE statement looks like this:

`INSERT myTable (id, startTime) VALUES(1234, 123456)`

`UPDATE myTable SET startTime = 123456 WHERE id = 1234`

`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM myTable ORDER BY startTime`

I tried using transactions with no luck.

**More UPDATE**:

I think this is actually a problem with INSERT, not UPDATE. The SELECT statement always tries to get the latest row sorted by time. But since INSERT does not do any table-level locking, it's possible that SELECT will get old data. Is there a way to force table-level locking when doing INSERT?

Comment: shall you publish the samples of the SELECT and UPDATEs....

Comment: What [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html) are you using? This could occur if you are using `READ UNCOMMITTED` or 'dirty reads'.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Whatever the default isolation level is for InnoDB, not sure if that answers your questions.

Comment: @pixelfreak check out my answer to do this in a different way......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query cache isn't the issue. Writes invalidate the cache.

MySQL gives priority to writes and with the default isolation level (REPEATABLE READ), your SELECT would have to wait for the UPDATE to finish.

INSERT can be treated differently if you have [CONCURRENT INSERTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/concurrent-inserts.html) enabled for MyISAM, also InnoDB uses record locking, so it doesn't have to wait for inserts at the end of the table.

Could this be a race condition then? Are you sure your SELECT occurs after the UPDATE? Are you reading from a replicated server where perhaps the update hasn't propagated yet?

If the issue is with the concurrent INSERT, you'll want to disable CONCURRENT INSERT on MyISAM, or explicitly lock the table with LOCK TABLES during the INSERT. The solution is the same for InnoDB, explicitly lock the table on the INSERT with LOCK TABLES.

Comment: @pixelfreak, I just updated my answer about INSERT. You either need to turn that feature off with MyISAM or explicitly lock the table with LOCK TABLES.

Comment: Marcus, I am using InnoDB, not MyISAM

Comment: @pixelfreak, InnoDB uses record locking, so SELECTs are not blocked by inserts at end of table. The solution is the same. Use LOCK TABLES to explicitly lock the table when you are inserting. Sorry, I was updating my answer as I went too, and I though you said your UPDATE was the problem, not the INSERT. :)

Answer (score 0):

A)
If you dont need the caching at all(for any SELECT), disable the query 
cache completely.

B)
If you want this for only one session, you can do it like
"set session query_cache_type=0;" which will set this for that 
perticular session.

use SQL_NO_CAHCE additionally in either case.

Comment: 1) Add one more column like 'update' with default as 0              2) Make it 1 while oding the update itslef.                         In the SELECT use "WHERE update = 1" condition additionally.